# Question on Flask-SQLAlchemy / updating a parent Class on a Child delete

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this issue which I do not know how to manage, other than writing the same code in different spots. What I want is that after an object is deleted, it makes a call to its parent object to update itself with new information. I tried using the SQLAlchemy event `after_delete`, but since it's within a commit, I can't seem to change the information of the other object. I get a `ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed`. I feel like it should be the deletion of the pick itself that calls on its parent to update itself, or somehow for the parent to notice the presence/absence of children, but I don't know how to trigger that.

A user can have many picks. A pick belongs to a user, and has one media attached to it. Here is an example of the code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func, event
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import set_attribute
from names_generator import generate_name
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'
#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

    picks = db.relationship('Pick', back_populates='user', cascade='all, delete')

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'User: {self.name}'

class Media(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    abandoned_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    picks = db.relationship('Pick', back_populates='media', cascade='all, delete')

    def check_abandoned(self):
        if self.picks:
            print(f'{self} is not abandoned')
            self.abandoned_date = None
        else:
            print(f'{self} was abandoned')
            self.abandoned_date = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()
        

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Movie: {self.title}'

class Pick(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    #Relations
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    media_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('media.id'))

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='picks')
    media = db.relationship('Media', back_populates='picks')

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Pick by {self.user.name} on {self.media.title}'
    
    def __init__(self, user, media) -> None:
        self.user = user
        self.media = media

@db.event.listens_for(Pick, 'after_delete')
@db.event.listens_for(Pick, 'after_insert')
def pick_deleted(mapper, connection, target):
    print(f'Deleted or added {target}')
    #Perform status update here?

    #This method causes issues because I cannot perform a commit within a commit, as I get error messages saying This transaction is closed
    #target.media.check_abandoned()

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    users = User.query.all()
    medias = Media.query.all()
    picks = Pick.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', users=users, medias=medias, picks=picks)

@app.route('/generate_user')
def generate_user():
    user = User(name=generate_name(style='capital'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/generate_media')
def generate_media():
    media = Media(title=generate_name())
    db.session.add(media)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/generate_pick')
def generate_pick():
    random_user = User.query.order_by(func.random()).first()
    random_media = Media.query.order_by(func.random()).first()
    pick = Pick(user=random_user, media=random_media)
    db.session.add(pick)
    db.session.commit()
    #What I want to avoid
    #pick.media.check_abandoned()
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/delete_user/<user_id>')
def delete_user(user_id):
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    #What I want to avoid
    '''
    for pick in user.picks:
        db.session.delete(pick)
        db.session.commit()
        pick.media.check_abandoned()
    '''
    db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/delete_media/<media_id>')
def delete_media(media_id):
    media = Media.query.get(media_id)
    db.session.delete(media)
    db.session.commit()
    #This also deletes the pick because of the cascade relationship
    return redirect("/")

@app.route('/delete_pick/<pick_id>')
def delete_pick(pick_id):
    pick = Pick.query.get(pick_id)
    db.session.delete(pick)
    db.session.commit()
    #What I want to avoid
    #pick.media.check_abandoned()
    return redirect("/")
```

Any idea on how to do this best?

I also looked into `@db.event.listens_for(Media.picks, 'dispose_collection')`
But I can't get this to trigger. Most likely because it's not actually disposing the collection?
That and I looked into `@db.event.listens_for(Media.picks, 'append')`, which does not work as the pick is not yet in session? `SAWarning: Object of type <Pick> not in session, add operation along 'User.picks' will not proceed (This warning originated from the Session 'autoflush' process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)`

And `@db.event.listens_for(Media.picks, 'remove')` never triggers on my end.

Thanks!